# Oro CRM - Cann't istall node-sass Version

Tags: orocrm, orocommerce

I get the following error:

```
 Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.12.0/linux-x64-83_binding.node":
  HTTP error 404 Not Found
  Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
        try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.
        export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

  or configure npm proxy via
        npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080
```

No, i don't use a proxy.
The following dependencies are installed:

```
  gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
  gyp info using node@14.6.0 | linux | x64
```

That's the information i get from *composer info | grep oro/*:

```
oro/calendar-bundle                  4.1.5      Calendar bundle for OroPlatform-based applications.
oro/commerce                         4.1.6      OroCommerce - an open-source Business to Business Commerce ap...
oro/commerce-crm                     4.1.3      OroCRM integration for OroCommerce
oro/crm                              4.1.6      OroCRM
oro/crm-call-bundle                  4.1.5      Oro Call Bundle
oro/crm-dotmailer                    4.1.5      Oro Dotmailer integration
oro/crm-hangouts-call-bundle         4.1.1      Oro Google Hangouts integration
oro/crm-magento-embedded-contact-us  4.1.2      OroCRM Magento Embedded Contact Us package
oro/crm-task-bundle                  4.1.4      Oro Task Bundle
oro/crm-zendesk                      4.1.3      OroCRM Zendesk Integration
oro/customer-portal                  4.1.6
oro/doctrine-extensions              1.2.2      Doctrine Extensions for MySQL and PostgreSQL.
oro/marketing                        4.1.4      Oro Marketing Bundles
oro/oauth2-server                    4.1.4      Oro OAuth 2.0 authorization and resource server for BAP
oro/platform                         4.1.6      Business Application Platform (BAP)
oro/platform-serialised-fields       4.1.2      OroPlatform Serialized Fields
oro/redis-config                     4.1.2      OroRedisConfigBundle
```

I tried to open the above link in my browser and get a 404 Error. But if i tried to install the latest version this works.
To get to my question, can I upgrade the version of this package? Or is there another solution to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can upgrade, but currently, it's not that easy to upgrade node-sass in the OroCRM project.

You have to patch the [vendor/oro/platform/build/package.json](https://github.com/oroinc/platform/blob/master/build/package.json#L46) file. The team is going to simplify this in further 4.1 releases.

Comment: Can you explain why it is not easy to upgrade node-sass? I have adapted the package.json, there is no error anymore, but the installation seems to hang up.

Comment: > but the installation seems to hang up.
It may happen when you use root user or sudo to run the command. Try also to drop the node_modules after changing package.json.

Comment: > why it is not easy to upgrade node-sass? - I mean, you have to patch the vendor file, that is not the preferred way to customize an application.